# android keyboard

Tags: android

Hi
I have added a new button in android virtual keyboard and gave name Done. Now i want to perform some action by pressing Done button. How to do this can any body help?

Thanks & Regards.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
doneBtn.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() { 
    @Override 
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {                       
        //action to be performed                    
    }
}
```

Comment: This code catches Done key press and performs what you put in `onEditorAction`